# jQuery methods (.css, .html, etc) not working inside for

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops, methods

Is there a reason why the methods are working outside the loop and not inside? I'm not even working with the positions yet and color or text change are not working either.

To extend the question a bit more, what I'm trying to do is to change the text of different table positions. The iteration is working fine too.

```
       $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(5)').css("color", "red");

       for (var i = 0; i < fechas.length; i++) {
           for (var j = 0; j < nombres.length; j++) {
                $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > th:nth-child(3)').css("color", "red");
                 $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(4) > th:nth-child(4)').html("val");

              }
         }

       $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)').css("color", "red");
       $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)').html('HOLA');
```

I'll add the HTML too

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla_servicios" style="width:100%; padding:12px">
<tbody id="tbody_tabla">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>2014-01-01 00:00:00</th>
        <th>2014-02-13 00:00:00</th>
        <th>2014-03-01 00:00:00</th>
        <th>2014-04-01 00:00:00</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value2</th>
        <td>2,2</td>
        <td>2,3</td>
        <td>2,4</td>
        <td>2,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value3</th>
        <td>3,2</td>
        <td>3,3</td>
        <td>3,4</td>
        <td>3,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value4</th>
        <td>4,2</td>
        <td>4,3</td>
        <td>4,4</td>
        <td>4,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value5</th>
        <td>5,2</td>
        <td>5,3</td>
        <td>5,4</td>
        <td>5,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value6</th>
        <td>6,2</td>
        <td>6,3</td>
        <td>6,4</td>
        <td>6,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value7</th>
        <td>7,2</td>
        <td>7,3</td>
        <td>7,4</td>
        <td>7,5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value8</th>
        <td>8,2</td>
        <td>8,3</td>
        <td>8,4</td>
        <td>8,5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs4djbrd/1/)**

Comment: Please show the corresponding HTML so we can test your code.

Comment: The content in the loop is static so not sure what the point of the loop is.

Comment: Do you realize you are selecting the same elements over and over again inside the loop? What are you trying to do exactly? What do `i` and `j` correspond to?

Comment: @epascarello Of course, it's just testing, once the static position works, I'll move forward to using the variables.

Comment: Show us your HTML code please.

Comment: @Alok HTML code added.

Comment: You still haven't shown the code that declares `fechas` and `nombres`

Comment: The jQuery methods work fine. It's your selectors that are faulty. https://jsfiddle.net/xs4djbrd/2/

Comment: @isherwood true. Why are they wrong anyway if it's the unique selector? Why can't I iterate over them?

Comment: You really need to update your question to remove all the irrelevant jQuery stuff and just ask about the CSS selectors.

Comment: The selector outside your loop is looking for `td` child elements that do exist in your markup and the selectors inside your loop are looking for `th` child elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen subselects like that before.

```
$('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(5)')
```

I think its bad practice to have code search for the cell when a named cell is faster, and easier to debug too. Why don't you name/number the td tags?

```
$("#tbody_tabla > tr").eq(3).children().eq(5).css("color", "red");
```

The above might work.  Failing that, provide sample HTML so folk got a better chance of helping you.

See also: http://api.jquery.com/find/

EDITED: @joseph-marikle suggested using children() instead of find()

Comment: should probably use [`children('td')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead of `find()` to stay closer to the original selector.

Comment: Not working does not give anyone an idea on what did not work - it only says you did not get your desired output. Break your code down in to chunks - first get your table, make sure the output is what you expect - then get the 3rd tr tag, write it to the console, make sure it too is correct, then get the 5th td tag, write it to the console. And... share your html code otherwise folk will waste your time with false answers (and you'll waste their time with their attempts to help proving worthless)

Comment: Yes, edit, the problem was the selectors were wrong. So @JosephMarikle was right, using "children" worked for static test, not with the loop though.

Answer (score 0):

> The selector outside your loop is looking for `td` child elements that
>   do exist in your markup and the selectors inside your loop are looking
>   for `th` child elements that don't exist.

In the fiddle you provided, you have this in the loop:

```
    $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > th:nth-child(3)').css("color", "red");
    $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(4) > th:nth-child(4)').html("val");
```

But it should be:

```
    $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3)').css("color", "red");
    $('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(4)').html("val");
```

Because there wont' be multiple `th` elements in any other row besides row 1.

Also, I'm at a loss for what your loops do in the fiddle since you aren't using the loop variables anywhere. You are just looping over the same elements over and over attempting to do the same thing each time.

Comment: Yes, I added a comment explaining it, I was wondering why it wasn't working inside the loop even if it was the same static position. Once it worked with static positions I moved on to working with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your this part of code

```
$('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(3) > th:nth-child(3)').css("color", "red");
$('#tbody_tabla > tr:nth-child(4) > th:nth-child(4)').html("val");
```

here you are looking for 3rd th element directly as a child of 3rd tr from the table.

But you have a look at your code you will see within each tr there is only one th , so it wont find the 3rd or 4th th in later cases with a tr.

```
Problematic part
    > th:nth-child(3)
    > th:nth-child(4)
```

Solution

1) Either change this th to td and adjust the element number

```
> td:nth-child(4)
> td:nth-child(5)
```

2) Change all td to th and you code will work

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xs4djbrd/5/